# Convert octet-stream to image

Tags: javascript, image

I need to fetch a file using a $http.get.
The data returns as application/octet-stream
But i know this file is an image.

How can i display this file as an image?

I tried

```
var nuroImage = new Image();
nuroImage.onload = function {
  scope.imageSrc = this.src;
}

$http(req).then(
  funciton(response) {
    nuroImage.src = "data:application/octet-stream," + response.data
  }
```

I get 200ok but the image isn't showing

Is it possible to transform octet-stream to jpeg/png?

Comment: If the response is already a `data URI` try removing `"data:application/octet-stream,"` at second example. Can you include first 15 to 20 characters of returned string at Question?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to request image as `Blob`, [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create a blob URL from response

```js
(async () => {
  const res = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/image/png')
  const blob = await res.blob()
  const img = new Image()
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

  // newer promise based version of img.onload
  await img.decode()
  
  document.body.append(img)

  // Don't forget to revoke the blob url when 
  // you no longer need it (to release memory)
  URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)
})()
```

Comment: I have the same question except im not using fetch to get the data. i have a file which contains application/octet-stream and i want to convert it to an image how do i do that?

Answer (score 6):

I guess you should something like this:

- Use `atob` to encode the resulting run-length compressed image file
- And use `<img src="data:image/png;base64,....">` to include that into the html5 file

If your file is not PNG, do add corresponding mime type.

**Sample**:

```html
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/
f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67
QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g7
7ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7"/>
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/integrating/

Answer (score -2):

if somebody here using axios and facing issue converting  application/octet-stream  binary in  image/octet-stream or  base64 then please don't use axios instead you can use fetch api of(modern browser to fetch api data ) it will solve that issue.

```js
fetch('https://picsum.photos/536/354', {
    method: 'GET',
})
.then((data) => {
    // IMP to convert your json or other response to blob ( for this you have to check your api response is file / binary 
    return data.blob()
})
.then((data) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {                         
        var b64 = reader.result
        console.log("This is base64", b64)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(data)
})
.catch((error) => {
    error.text().then( errorMessage => {
        console.log(errorMessage)
    })
})
```

Comment: Don't use the FileReader to read blob as base64 - Use `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` instead