# Next.js failed external image with extension in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have products with images("next": "^10.1.3",) from few different remote servers. Now I want to add next.js image for this. But after code update images from one server don't show(with other all fine). I think it could be related to file extension in URL but not sure in 100%.

Example `https://zoom.ocado.com/productImages/518/518554011_518554011_0_1601386321000_1280x1280.jpg`
Next js doesn't show this image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: As of `12.3` - You can whitelist one or more similar domains by using glob patterns.

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: '**.ocado.com',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Read more about it [here in this changelog](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-3#remote-patterns-stable)

---

Quoting from [Next.js doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#configuration)

> To enable Image Optimization for images hosted on an external website,
> use an absolute url for the Image src and specify which domains are
> allowed to be optimized

Therefore, add this into your `next.config.js`;

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['zoom.ocado.com'],
  },
}
```

### Serving for `application/octet-stream` content type response

Since the image URL that you provide serves it as `application/octet-stream`, which is a wrong mime type for serving images - There is no straight-forward way to use `next/image`.

However, you can still do the following;

1. Use next.js `v11.0.2-canary.4` - They recently fix this issue [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v11.0.2-canary.4)
2. Use `unoptimized` image - As the name suggests, next.js won't optimize your image at build time. E.g.

```
<Image src="https://zoom.ocado.com/productImages/518/518554011_518554011_0_1601386321000_1280x1280.jpg"
   alt="Test"
   layout="fill"
   unoptimized={true} 
/>
```

Comment: No. i already have this config. And this config(i have 3 different sources) works for images from other sources, but not for this(and all links for this source includes file extension).

Comment: @МаксимШутков I just noticed that, the image URL that you provide serves it as `application/octet-stream` - It's the server's issue that needs to be addressed. You can still use it by using [this answer's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37510957/1627271)

Comment: Is that mean that next js image optimization not working for that?

Comment: @МаксимШутков There is no straight-forward way for this as of now. Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

check response of server and also check extensions of the file.i think this is your problem.

Comment: 400 error for images only for that source. Images from other sources returns correct.